# Does the Mongoose hydrate method request a new query to the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question about Mongoose. Does the `Model.hydrate(rawDoc)` method request a new query to the database? I am using aggregate method to build my query and I need to use virtuals getter, because aggregate will be returned an plain object javascript so I cannot use any features instance from mongoose document object (e.g: virtuals, statics, methods, helpers, ...). What I am doing is converting a plain javascript object returned from this aggregate to mongoose document object by using `hydrate()` method, but I am wondering if this way does 2 queries to database or one query only?

```
const rawDocs = await Model.aggregate([...]);
const newDocs = rawDocs.map(doc => Model.hydrate(doc));

console.log(newDocs); // virtual fields are defined.
```

Comment: hydrate is a local operation and does not make an additional database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose `.hydrate()` is just a way to create a Mongoose Document from a raw JS object. [Docs here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.hydrate()).

Creating the document you can access to methods, virtuals, validations as you want... but it's not a object retrieved from the DB.

By the way, by definition, `.hydrate()` is the opposite from `.lean()` which also doesn't need an extra call and is similar to do `new Model()` but this last can trigger any DB query (from hooks for example).

So you should not have any extra DB call using `.hydrate()`.